# Count/adding +1 via if loop in a list.(adding one element IF a certain condition is true)

Tags: python, list, loops

i am trying to find out, since i am starting to learn python, how can I create a loop that only adds one element to a given list, IF a certain condition is true.

In my example, I wanted to create a dice game and then collect the number of times a certain value from 2 to 12 appears, either in 11 single lists or in one list.

How can I manage that?

EDIT: here some more details to better review my question and my task

```
import random

player_input = input("how many rounds? ")

def main():
    roll1 = 0
    roll2 = 0 
    rounds = 1

while rounds <= int(player_input):
        roll1 = dice_roll()
        roll2 = dice_roll()
        third = roll1 + roll2
        print("third: " + str(third)) 
        rounds = rounds + 1

# Here I want to insert the loop that outputs the appearance of a certain value that comes from the addition of two dice rolls.-->
#####
#here is what i´ve tried so far:

        two = 0
        if third == 2:
            two = two + 1
        print(two)
            
        three = 0
        if third == 3:
            three = three + 1
        print(three)
### it only updates the variable one time, and each time from 0 again

def dice_roll():
    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
    return diceRoll

main()
```

the output of the code above is like

```
how many rounds?  33
third: 4
0
0
third: 2
1
0
third: 5
0
0
....
third: 10
0
0
third: 6
0
0
third: 2
1
0
.....
```

The Variable falls back to value 0 every time the loop iterates, so it cant accumulate the total amount, the condition becomes true

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question isn't clear, please add your current code and/or clear example of the required action

Comment: Yes thank you, i edited my post so i hope now its more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood, you need to count the occurrences of 2 and 3. The issue in your code was, you were defining `two` and `three` inside the loop, because of which they were reset to zero every time. Moving them outside the loop, it becomes:

```
player_input = input("how many rounds? ")

def main():
    roll1 = 0
    roll2 = 0 
    rounds = 1
    two = 0
    three = 0
    while rounds <= int(player_input):
        roll1 = dice_roll()
        roll2 = dice_roll()
        third = roll1 + roll2
        print("third: " + str(third)) 
        rounds = rounds + 1

        if third == 2:
            two += two + 1
            
        if third == 3:
            three = three + 1

def dice_roll():
    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
    return diceRoll

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if condition:
  myList.append(x) # or do something else
```

Here `condition` is your condition and inside `myList` is your list.

Comment: Thanks, i edited m post, so that it becomes more clear what my problem is. I want an iteration but WITH the check in every time the loop iterates, if a certain condition is true. IF the condition is true, I want to increase the value of a certain variable OR a list by + 1.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is "dense" version of what you are looking for.
The code uses defaultdict as a way to count the occurrences of each roll combination.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(int)
player_input = input("how many rounds? ")
rounds = 0
while rounds <= int(player_input):
        roll1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        roll2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        data[roll1 + roll2] += 1
        rounds += 1
print(data)
```

Comment: thank you for that dense version. Its still to ambitious for me, I am working on the basic understandings of coding and python. Here you need to add a library with a certain function is that right?

Comment: @BenjaminDiLorenzo No need for any external library. `defaultdict` is part of python core (just like `random`). The code uses a dict in order to count how many times  each roll pair is found.